# Make all the sixes. Fun

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Given the following it is possible to complete each case so that they are all true? (i.e. so that the equation .... = 6 is true)

You can add any mathematical operations and parentheses but you cannot add any numbers.

i.e. $\sqrt{4}$ is fine but $\sqrt[3]{8}$ is not.

So...

$$0\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }0\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }0 = 6$$
$$1\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }1\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }1 = 6$$
$$2\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }2\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }2 = 6$$
$$3\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }3\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }3 = 6$$
$$4\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }4\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }4 = 6$$
$$5\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }5\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }5 = 6$$
$$6\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }6\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }6 = 6$$
$$7\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }7\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }7 = 6$$
$$8\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }8\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }8 = 6$$
$$9\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }9\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }9 = 6$$

For example, the number 6 line could be...

$$6+6-6 = 6$$

There are no trick questions here and it doesn't require using the $\neq$ sign.

Can you find the correct mathematical operations and parentheses to complete each line?

Comment: Is "e" a number? Or $\pi$?

Comment: But what has to be done??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar no. No numbers of any kind are required. Just add mathematical symbols to make each equation true. Like I have shown in the line for 6s.

Comment: @Aniket yes they would be counted as numbers. No numbers of any kind are required other than the ones in each incomplete equation :)

Comment: I believe that "add mathematical operations and parentheses" might better describe your challenge.  Generally Math.SE content should involve genuine questions to which users want answers.  It seems that you already know the answer to what you asked.  Please review [ask].

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on the [Puzzling Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MichaelBurr possibly. I didn't know that existed but also, given that there is a "recreational-maths" tag that describes exactly what I'm asking I assumed this would be ok.

Comment: @hardmath as a seasoned user of StackOverflow I know how to ask a question. I'm not sure which part of your link you are referring me to that I have not followed. If that is the case then the recreational-mathematics description needs to change :)

Comment: When you ask "can you complete them", are you asking for each case whether it can be completed or not, or are you implying that they all have solutions and asking whether we can find them?

Comment: @joriki edited to remove any possible misunderstanding or syntactically pedantic alternate interpretation of what is just supposed to be a little bit of fun. LOL! That is (after all) what the `recreational-mathematics` tag describes. :)

Comment: $8-\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}$ works for $8$. Can you use factorial?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger yup :) also, seems you got the hardest one first :D

Comment: If you can use factorials, then that explains the zeros?  Am I right?

Comment: $(0!+0!+0!)!=6$, and $(1+1+1)!=6$. I doubt you need factorial for any others.

Comment: $6=2+2+2=3\cdot 3-3=5+5/5=7-7/7$

Comment: Yeah, the rest are easy. Just don't forget square roots.

Comment: hey i have other for 5 $5^3/5^3$+5=6  (1.1.1)!=6  2.2+2=6 and cube root (6.6.6)=6   $3^3/3-3=6$  and many others can be done in similar way.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar to raise to the power of any numbers and to use any root greater than square root requires adding a number to the equation :)

Comment: oh so i add 0. is it fine now.

Answer (score 3):

$$(0! + 0! + 0!)! = 6$$
$$(1 + 1 + 1)! =6$$
$$2 + 2+ 2 = 6$$
$$3! +3 - 3 = 6$$
$$4 + 4 - \sqrt{4} = 6$$
$$5+5/5 = 6$$
$$7 - 7/7 = 6$$
$$\lfloor \sqrt{8} \rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt{8} \rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt{8} \rfloor =6$$
$$\sqrt{9} + (9 / \sqrt{9}) = 6$$

Comment: Nice. I like how you got the 8s to work. There is another way that doesn't require the "floor" operation :-) still works though.

Comment: Oof, floor function? I know he never specified what we can use, but I think I like the other one better.

Comment: Oh noooo! you got it earlier by $41s$. 
Good job, man....Stupid luck

Comment: Also, I'm surprised $3\times3-3$ didn't occur to you first.

Comment: The equation for $8$ would work for $7$, $6$, and $5$ as well (and also for $4$, for that matter).  Likewise $\lceil \sqrt k\rceil$ for $k=3$ and $2$.